# Creating an array with values that obey a criteria of smallest distance to the mean

Tags: julia

I am trying to build credible bands in Julia, however, there is a technical procedure that I am not aware of how to do. The code is the following:

```
#Significance level 95%
alpha_sign=0.05
#Genrate random values
N_1 = 100
Fs_1 = Array{Float64}(undef, length(x), N_1);

x = 0.0:0.01:1.0
for k in 1:100
  f = rand(postΠ)
  Fs_1[:,k] = f.(x)
end

# sup|theta_i(t)-average|


dif_b=Array{Float64}(undef, length(x),N);
for k in 1:100
dif_b[:,k] = Fs_1[:,k]-average_across
end



#Defining a function that allows to compute the n smallest values
using Base.Sort

function smallestn(a, n)
  sort(a; alg=Sort.PartialQuickSort(n))[1:n]
end



#Compute the maximum of the difference across time
sup_b=Array{Float64}(undef, N_1)
for k in 1:100
sup_b[k]=(maximum(abs.(dif_b[:,k] )))
end

#Build a matrix with the smallest distances
N_min=(1-alpha_sign)*N
using Base.Sort
min_sup_b=smallestn(sup_b,95)
```

To simplify the problem I am creating this example:
Imagine I have the matrix down there and I want to create a matrix with the values that are closest to the mean. I am able to compute the distances and store into a vector as displayed in the code above and later get the smallest values but I need to get back to the original matrix to extract those values.

```
X=[1,2,7,4,5]
av_X=mean(X,dims=1)
```

**Question**:

I am able to compute the distances and store them into a vector as displayed in the code above and later get the smallest values but I need to get back to the original matrix to extract those values.
How do I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
using Statistics

arr = rand(1:20, (4, 4))
colmeans = [mean(col) for col in eachcol(arr)]
deltas = map(cart -> abs(arr[cart] - colmeans[first(Tuple(cart))]) => cart, CartesianIndices(arr))
sorteddeltas = sort(deltas, lt = (x, y) -> first(x) < first(y), dims=1)

sarr = zeros(Int, (4, 4))
for (i, d) in enumerate(sorteddeltas)
    sarr[i] = arr[last(d)]
end

println(arr) # [7 1 2 15; 18 7 14 10; 3 11 10 13; 7 14 20 8]

println(colmeans) # [8.75, 8.25, 11.5, 11.5]

println(sarr) # [7 11 10 13; 7 7 14 10; 3 14 2 8; 18 1 20 15]

println(sarr') # [7 7 3 18; 11 7 14 1; 10 14 2 20; 13 10 8 15]
```

This should give you a sorted list of pairs of the distances from the mean of each column, with the second part of the pair the Cartesian coordinates of the original matrix.

sarr is the original matrix sorted column-major by closeness to the mean for each column.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the case of your example, the matrix I want to order according to the distance is arr. That is what I am struggling with.

Comment: I edited the answer to add a sorted version of arr. Note column major means the closest values to the mean are read down on the left.

Comment: Your answer is splendid. Thanks! However in my original example I have a matrix or array of dimensions 100 by 100, that means that for each collumn I need to compute the distance using max(col1-average),max(col2-average)...max(col100-average). I tried but I do not know how to adapt your code to this case, because instead of identifying each element with the distance I need to idetify each collumn with the distance. If you could provide an update to your answe with this problem, i would be very thankful.

Comment: If you mean the mean of each column I have revised the answer for that.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I am going to study more carefully your answer. But I did not mean the average of each column, but the distance between each column and the average given by max(column 1-average), max(column 2 - average)...max(column 100-average). According to the distances that I calculated, I want the 95 columns with the smallest distances. I hope now is clearer.

Comment: is the average the overall matrix average or the column average?  Is the max the max in the overall matrix or the max diff in each column or the max average among columns? All that may change is how you compute the deltas.

Answer (score 0):

I think the function you are looking for is `findmin()`. It gives both the minimum value and its index.

```
julia> x = randn(5)
5-element Vector{Float64}:
 -0.025159738348978562
 -0.24720173332739662
 -0.32508319212563325
  0.9470582053428686
  1.1467087893336048

julia> findmin(x)
(-0.32508319212563325, 3)
```

If you want to do this for every column in a matrix, you can do something like:

```
julia> X = randn(3, 5)
3×5 Matrix{Float64}:
  1.06405    1.03267    -0.826687   -1.68299   0.00319586
 -0.129021   0.0615327   0.0756477   1.05258   0.525504
  0.569748  -0.0877886  -1.48372     0.823895  0.319364

julia> min_inds = [findmin(X[:, i]) for i = 1:5]
5-element Vector{Tuple{Float64, Int64}}:
 (-0.12902069012799203, 2)
 (-0.08778864856976668, 3)
 (-1.4837211369655696, 3)
 (-1.6829919363620507, 1)
 (0.003195860366775878, 1)
```

Comment: But I need to find the minumum distance to the mean and then I need to find the values from the original matrix that match that minum distance. So I need to select of my original matrix the values with the criteria that they staisfy the minimum distance or at least order them according to that criteria. If you could provide the procedure to do that I would be very grateful.